# WPF Compilation Errors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn .NET and WPF, and I'm making a calculator type application to learn some of the framework.  I have XAML code that looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="CS_WPF_TEST.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Name="DisplayBox" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <Button Margin="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="MC" Content="MC" Click="ClearMem" />
        <Button Margin="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="MR" Content="MR" Click="RecallMem" />
        /snip/
        <Button Margin="4" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Name="Plus" Content="+" Click="Plus" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And C# Code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CS_WPF_TEST
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //snip
        //event handlers with declarations like following
        private void Handle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //code
        }
    }
}


<Button Margin="4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Name="Caret" Content="^" Click="Exponent" />
<Button Margin="4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Name="Sqrt" Content="Sqrt" Click="Sqrt" />
```

And the corrosponding Event Handler Code:

```
private void Exponent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    process_operation((a, b) => System.Math.Pow(a, b));
}
private void Seven(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    process_input('7');
}
```

But for some reason, I have no errors on exponent, but I am getting errors like the following on Seven:

```
c:\snip\CS_WPF_TEST\CS_WPF_TEST\MainWindow.xaml(34,49): error CS0102: The type 'CS_WPF_TEST.MainWindow' already contains a definition for 'Seven'
C:\snip\CS_WPF_TEST\CS_WPF_TEST\MainWindow.xaml.cs(264,22): (Related location)
```

Is my syntax wrong, or is there something I don't know about, like the order things are declared in or something?

Comment: Do you happen to have a Button on your Page which you have named "Seven"? It might be contending with your Method Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the same name for your XAML controls and your event handlers. Don't do that.